# Difference Between "a Movie" or "the Movie"

Tags: articles

I'm learning English so I need your help to build my English better. I'm searching about my problem but didn't find.
My question is when we use "a Movie" or "The Movie"

Comment: It's impossible to answer that unless you tell us the sentence in which you want to use it.

Comment: You can google "the vs a." "The," or the "definite article," is used in many situations and "a", or the "indefinite article," is also used in many. To make this question answerable, please ask about a certain situation.

Answer (score 1):

You would use "a" when speaking about movies in general, as in "I'm planning on seeing a movie this weekend", here "a movie" indicates that you haven't chosen what movie you are going to see.

"The movie starts at three", while not naming the particular film does indicate that you have a particular movie in mind (presumably known from the rest of the conversation).